# Button not being disabled when audio files are playing

Tags: jquery, button, audio, disabled-control

I have a list of words and their corresponding audio files. When a button is clicked, the audio files play consecutively, This part works OK. But the button is not being disabled while a list is being played. So it is possible to have a list being played several times at once. Here is the html:

```
    <a class="repeat_btn" href="#"><span class="fa fa-repeat fa_repeat_ws"></span></a>
```

and here is the jquery code:

```
    "use strict";
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("a.repeat_btn").click(function (evnt) {
        evnt.stopPropagation();
        jQuery(this).attr("disabled","disabled");                         // to disable button
        var engWords = jQuery("span.audio"),
          pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML,
          audioElement = document.createElement("audio"),
          audioType = Modernizr.audio.ogg? ".ogg": ".mp3",
          i = 0;
        audioPlay(i);
        audioElement.addEventListener( "ended", function() {
          i++;
            if ( i < 100 ) {
              audioPlay(i);
            }
        });
        function audioPlay(i)  {
          var wordList = jQuery("span#"+engWords[i].id),
            audioPath = pathVar+engWords[i].id+audioType;
          wordList.addClass("set_font_green");
          audioElement.src = audioPath;
          audioElement.play();
          jQuery.doTimeout(1000, function()  {
           wordList.removeClass("set_font_green");
         });
        }
        jQuery(this).removeAttr("disabled");   // to enable the button
      });
    });
```

My question is what needs to be done to ensure the button is disabled while a word list is being played and enabled again when the word list has finished playing.

Comment: `disabled` does not work on anchors `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the `property` disabled is not in the standard for anchor elements; only buttons. I'd suggest you just add a class to it instead, and only proceed if the class is not present.

```
jQuery("a.repeat_btn").click(function (evnt) {
    // stop if the class is present
    if (this.classList.contains('disabled'))
        return;
    this.classList.add('disabled');
    // rest of code ...

    // enable again
    this.classList.remove('disabled');
});
```

Code above is not IE8 compatible, due to the use of `classList`.

Comment: this doesn't work if  this.classList.remove('disabled'); is placed within the scope of the click function but does work if  this.classList.remove('disabled'); is placed within the scope of the document ready function, but then the page has to be refreshed to play thru the list again

Comment: I think you got it all wrong. `this` refers to the DOMNode that the event is being bound to, inside the callback function.

Comment: I placed the code  within the callback function as you indicated but multiple playing still occurs. any suggestions :)